# I am trying to connect my firebase realtime databse to cloud firestore but its giving me import errors

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I and trying to add a online functionality to my chat app. For that I have built a presence system using firebase realtime databse with the code below.

db is getfirestore and dbt is getdatabase

```
import { auth, db, dbt } from "@/firebase/firebase";
import { ref as rtdbRef, set, onValue, onDisconnect } from "firebase/database";
const connectedRef = rtdbRef(dbt, ".info/connected");
const myConnectionsRef = rtdbRef(dbt, `status/` + user.uid);
onValue(connectedRef, (snap) => {
  if (snap.val() === false) {
  return ;
}
onDisconnect(myConnectionsRef).set("disconnected").then(() => {
  updateFirestoreUser(true, user);
  set(myConnectionsRef, "connected")
});
```

I am using firestore cloud for storing users data, and database only for presence system.
What I want is to connect this realtime database to cloud firestore so when users goes offline a variable named isOnline (created on sign up) in firestore cloud is turned false and similarly true when he connects back. I found this in firebase docs but its giving me errors in each line:
firebase,firebase, firestore(), database() not defined.

```
var userStatusFirestoreRef = firebase.firestore().doc('/status/' + uid);
var isOfflineForFirestore = {
  state: 'offline',
  last_changed: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
};
var isOnlineForFirestore = {
  state: 'online',
  last_changed: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
};
firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val() == false) {
      userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore);
      return;
  };
  userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {
    userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
    userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForFirestore);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code updates a value in firestore cloud based on realtime database presence system. Its not exactly what you asked but a workaround.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const myConnectionsRef = rtdbRef(dbt, `status/` + currentUser?.uid);
    onValue(myConnectionsRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data);
        if(data === "connected"){
            updateFirestoreUser(true, currentUser);
        }else{
            updateFirestoreUser(false, currentUser);
        }
    });
    //eslint-disable-next-line
}, [])
```